# In JavaScript given an object property value, can I find a corresponding property name?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm passing a config object with names for each slide to a function that instantiates a jQuery tools scrollable. I want the URL in the location bar to match the active tab id. I have it working so that passing the URL with the name in will navigate to the correct slide (that's at the bottom of the provided code), but I'm trying to get the URL updating when the slide changes. I know what I need to do to get that, but not how to do that, which is like in the question title.. pass a value to an object and get a property that has that value.

```
$(function () {
    Scrollablenav.init({
        "#tulips": 0,
        "#daffodils": 1,
        "#zebras": 2,
        "#horseshoes": 3
    });
});

Scrollablenav.init = function(config){
    var scroller = $(".scrollable").scrollable({
        circular: true,
        onSeek: function (event) {
            parent.location.hash = function(){
            //something that looks at config, sends it the value of the current slide and returns corresponding property name
            }
        }
    }).navigator({
            navi: '#slideTabs',
            naviItem: 'a',
            activeClass: 'current',
            history: true
    }).data('scrollable');

    if (!isNaN(config[location.hash])){
        scroller.seekTo(config[location.hash], 0);
     }
}
```

Comment: Is that the only place you're using the config object? Why don't you just reverse the key/value or move them both into an object like @MikeChristensen said?

Comment: What if more than one property has the same value? Do you want the first matching property found, or an array of all, or...? I guess it won't happen with your example data, but still...

Comment: there shouldn't be any matches since it's indexes. considered doing a straight array and using the index values, but I still need to go both ways (ie for `scroller.seekTo(config[location.hash], 0);`)

Comment: Yeah I think you should store both in the map, then you can do `scroller.seekTo(config[location.hash].Index, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change the format of your config?  In other words, can we do:

```
$(function () {
    Scrollablenav.init({
        "#tulips": { Key: 'tulips', Index: 0 },
        "#daffodils": { Key: 'daffodils', Index: 1 },
        "#zebras": { Key: 'zebras', Index: 2 },
        "#horseshoes": { Key: 'horseshoes', Index: 3 }
    });
});
```

If that doesn't work, you can make a new object somewhere that maps the indexes back to the key:

```
var keys = {
   1: 'tulips',
   2: 'daffodils',
   3: 'zebras',
   4: 'horseshoes',
};
```

**UPDATE:**

You could also build this config dynamically:

```
$(function () {
    var values = ['#tulips', '#daffodils', '#zebras', '#horseshoes'];
    var config = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
       config[values[i]] = { Index: i, Key: values[i] };
    }

    Scrollablenav.init(config);
});
```

Comment: i imagine this would work, but I don't like having to put what's practically the same information in two places

Comment: I totally agree; if you *really* hate duplicating all the keys, you can build that config map using code instead.

Comment: I ended up without time to get this working exactly the way I wanted, but that looks like a solid implementation.

Answer (score 4):

**You can create your own function** to find property name based on its value:

```
function findPropertyName(object, property_value, strict) {
    if (typeof strict=='undefined'){
        strict = false;
    };
    for (property in object){
        if ((strict && object[property] === property_value) ||
            (!strict && object[property] == property_value)){
            return property;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Function description:

- It will return  name of the first property having given value, or `false` if no such property has been found.
- Third param is responsible for determining whether strict comparison should be made (eg. string "`123`" is equal to integer `123` - like in `'123'==123`, but not *strictly* equal - like in `'123'===123`).
- Function could be improved to return all the properties having given value, but I think you do not need it.

To check the function in action see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2YFh/).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
function getMyHash(config, value) {
  for (item in config) {
    if (config[item] === value) {
      return item;
    }
  }
};
```

basically you have to iterate and match values; you can't lookup by value.